# Lua: Why doesn't this coroutine loop finish?

Tags: lua

I'm working on a script for automated testing of a plugin for a stage lighting console (GrandMA2). As the plugin requires some user inputs, the test ist mainly about input fuzzing and therefore the plugin is run several times.
 This is done by making use of a coroutine that runs the test script and is getting yielded for every run of the main plugin. When the main plugin finishes, it resumes the test thread. This is done repeatedly until all input values hardcoded in the test file, are tested. That's the theory. In practice there appears a problem where the plugin is sometimes only run once. And if I close the console software, reopen it (without file saving), import the plugin and start it in test mode again, it is run 2 or 3 times. Repeating this, it now runs 4-5 times, and so on. But it never runs often enough to test all values. The best case is that it stops before the last run of the plugin.
You can have a look at some code below. But if you're encouraged, you can also read the whole code at GitHub (https://github.com/kochjo/CueStep-Fader). You only have to mind the files ```CSF_main.lua``` and ```Test.lua```.
This is not critical for the plugin itself, but as I'm still learning to code, I'm wondering why this is happening.
 ...And it get's me crazy. 
 **Code Snippet from the main file:**

```
local REQ_SUCCESS, Test = pcall(function() return require 'Test' end)
-- do some other stuff..
function CSF_main(testmode)
    --[[
        Requests user input for the number of steps and the CSF-name
        and executes all necessary functions in order.
    ]]
    if testmode and REQ_SUCCESS then
        TESTMODE = true
    elseif not REQ_SUCCESS then
        gma.echo('CSF plugin: Test script not found. Thus test mode is not available.')
    end
    -- do some other uninteresting stuff..
    if TESTMODE then coroutine.resume(Test.test); gma.echo("resumed") end
end
return CSF_main
```

**Code Snippet from the test file:**

```
Test.test = coroutine.create(function()
    --[[
        The main function for the test. It runs CSF repeatedly (with param. 'testmode' set to true)
        until all inputs listed in Test.lua are tested.
    ]]
    local run = 1
    while not all_tested() do
        log("Run", run, 'Not all tested. Next one.')
        cmd('LUA "CSF_main(true)"') -- execute the main plugin again via the console API..
        coroutine.yield() -- wait for the current run of CSF to finish.
        log(nil, nil, "\n Resume yielding loop.")
        run = run+1
    end
    log(nil, nil, "Test completed.") -- this is never reached..
    LOGFILE:close()
end)
```

This is my first question here on stackoverflow and I hope I explained everything in a way, that also people without knowledge about GrandMA2 lighting desks and their lua API can understand what my problem is.
Thanks in advance to everyone sacrificing his/her time for this!

Comment: Add `print/log` around `coroutine.resume(Test.test)` call to see its result printed. Either the control doesn't get to `resume` call or it fails on resuming a dead coroutine (or something along those lines).

Comment: I don't understand why you use coroutines at all. Was the task to run tests in parallel?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin I decided to run the test script in a coroutine because it gives me the possibility to yield the test until the main plugin is finished. I was trying to do it without a coroutine before, but this led to the problem, that the while loop in the test script continues to call the main plugin, even if the run before haven‘t been finished until then. This happens because ```CSF_main``` has to be called via the GrandMA2 cmd line and then runs in parallel to the test script.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko Thanks for your suggestion. I logged the result of the resume call and it turned out, that the coroutine is every time successfully resumed.. For me, it looks like the last ```cmd(‚LUA „CSF_main(true)“‘)``` call is simply not executed by the console. Maybe I should write an mail to the MA tech support.. That would explain why the test file never finishes. Looks like the test is waiting for the ```gma.cmd()``` method to return, what doesn‘t happen.